# Trying to add variable frequency and gain control to op amp function generator circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, oscilloscope, gain

I was using a [circuitstoday guide](https://www.circuitstoday.com/simple-function-generator-circuit) of a simple function generator using op amps and tried to repurpose it for variable amplitude control as well as frequency control using two potentiometers.

I designed the entire thing in Multisim and was hoping it would work, but for my final output, I am getting a sine wave with a DC component. Obviously, this is not optimal. Is my way of controlling the amplitude (where I drop the amplitude of the square wave from the relaxation oscillator via a voltage divider and then amplify the signal again at the next stage prior to the integrators) very poor?

Should I achieve variable voltage control through the voltage sources powering the op amps via a voltage divider with a potentiometer? Every build guide I find for a function generator either uses a microcontroller, a signal generator IC, or lacks variable amplitude and frequency control. I would like to use op amps in this design, it doesn't have to be the 741 nor the LM1458.

My attempts to play with resistance and capacitance values don't end well. Trying to maximize the bandwidth of the square wave generated by the relaxation oscillator inevitably ruins the outputs of the subsequent stages, or vice versa. Any and all help are appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the direction toward some resource.

If anyone wants the Multisim file, just ask. Not sure if I can upload it here.

[image: Circuit in Multisim with Oscilloscope Reading]

Comment: Circuitstoday is operated by students on the other side of the world. This function generator circuit design is VERY old and uses opamps that are 55 years old.

Comment: I figured as much. In another thread of someone who tried to use the same webpage, a very knowledgeable user criticized all of the component values and said it wouldn't work. I continue to tweak everything and it still isn't optimal.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to modify this to have variable frequency, because the conversion to triangle and sine are made with low pass filters. They work somehow acceptably only on a narrow frequency range that they are designed for. Except the sine probably is too distorted for high quality distortion measurements.

The square wave oscillator can easily have adjustable frequency, but seemingly you already know this.

Use a triangle wave oscillator - a Schmitt trigger senses the integrator output and drives the integrator. That's the very standard idea which has been used at least 60 years. It makes constant amplitude triangle. Change the charging current of the integrator to adjust the freqyency.

Convert the triangle to sine with a non-linear circuit. The common version uses diode-resistor network for it.

Making the design somehow optimal is a hefty task. Better to order a kit or imitate an old commercial instrument design like Wavetek 148A.

Another approach is to make it as a DSP system. Analog Devices AD9833 is for it. But the user interface must be programmed to a computer. You, of course, need the DC power, a robust adjustable output amp, case & connectors etc.

Get a kit is my suggestion if you want to build it.

Comment: I'll have to ponder all that you told me because things such as Schmitt triggers are still relatively new to me. I was able to get decent frequency control as well as amplitude control for the square wave but then ran into another issue. As you are probably aware, the amplitude of the integrators is partially dependent on the frequency of the input. Thus, adjusting "frequency" also meant adjusting amplitude. Thank you for the honest advice, it really is a big help.